# Importing Flask without installing

Tags: python, flask

How can I import flask without having to install it onto my computer. I want to do it with the files that I downloaded from the website. The reason is because I don't have the permissions to install a module on my school's server thus I need to figure out how to do it without installation.
My computer's OS is Windows 7 while my school computers run on ubuntu, linux.
PS: What does import * do?

Comment: Place the `flask` folder in the same directory as your Python file. Then you can do `import flask` or `from flask import Flask` etc. As for your last question, try reading the Python documentation.

Comment: Use [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/). It's a single Python file and is similar to Flask.

Comment: `from package_name import *` imports all of the symbols in the package or module that are "public" (e. g. that don't begin with an underscore or which are explicitly listed in the `__all__` list) into your current namespace.  In general, it is better to import *just* the names you need, to avoid surprise name collisions.

Comment: It hit an error when I tried to run it:

Comment: Error is from werkzeug.exceptions import abort and importerror: No module named werkzeug.exceptions

Comment: I believe Flask requires several additional packages for it to work, one of which is called werkzeug. You can find a list of dependencies within setup.py, and you install them in the same manner described by Anorov to locally make Flask available.

Answer (score 5):

Use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/). It lets you create python environment in a location you specify. Once the virtual environment is created, you can install Flask and your app inside this.

From the docs, virtualenv can be created locally, without installing the package globally:

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ python virtualenv.py myVE
```

Comment: its sounds good but I don't have the permission to install virtualenv on the school's computer

Comment: @dismal, the page I linked has a way to create virtualenv locally.

Comment: Must it really use virtualenv? because i really want to keep this as simple as i can make it.

Comment: @dismal, There is no added complexity with using virtualenv. There is no code change required on your app. You'll install packages, as you would in main environment. And good thing is, when you are ready you can port your app to main environment without any change.